# один ко многим в django

Tags: django, sqlite

На странице должен быть список вопросов и под каждым вопросом список ответов на него

view :

```
def get_home(request):

sql_req='Select polls_choice.id,polls_choice.choice_text from polls_choice,polls_question WHERE polls_choice.question_id=polls_question.id'
return render_to_response('questions.html',{'choices': Choice.objects.raw(sql_req), 'questions': Question.objects.all()})
```

html:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    {{ question.pub.date }}
    {{ question.question_text }}

    <h4>Choices</h4>
    <div class="choices">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <h3>new choice</h3>
        {{ choice.choice_text }}
        <p>votes: {{ choice.votes }}</p>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: У человека гугл не работает: http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one.html и http://habrahabr.ru/post/74967/

Comment: в данном варианте выводится список вопрос и к каждому вопросу все ответы из базы данных, что надо изменить, чтобы под каждым вопросом были только соответствующие ему ответы?